# Convert enumeration of methods to single multicast delegate in C#

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I have an `IEnumerable<ILog>` object called `loggers`.  `ILog` has a method called `Log` which matches the delegate `LogHandler`.  I'd like to create a single multicast delegate (logHandler) that calls *all* the `Log` methods in the enumeration.  One way to do it would be:

```
LogHandler logHandler;
foreach (var logger in loggers)
{
    logHandler += logger.Log;
}
```

I'm curious if there's a cleaner, one-liner way to do it.  So far, the best I've come up with is:

```
LogHandler logHandler = Delegate.Combine(loggers.Select(log => new LogHandler(log.Log) as Delegate).ToArray()) as LogHandler;
```

This seems a bit convoluted and unreadable.  I'm curious if there's a cleaner way than my two solutions.

Comment: or `loggers.ForEach(x => logHandler += logger.Log)`

Comment: @MichaelRandall Yea I like that, though I'll have to change my enumeration to a `List<T>` since `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't have a `ForEach` extension method.  Also I think you meant `x.Log` instead of `logger.Log`